# Android google map on click of current location button show alert box if gps not enabled

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented Google map in my app. When i click on the current location button i wanted to show alert box if Gps is not enabled.

I tried this way where i got the view of that button.

```
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        View plusMinusButton = fm.getView().findViewById(1);
        View locationButton = fm.getView().findViewById(2);
```

Using that `locationButton` i tried to use `setOnclickListener` but that did not help.

My requirement is simple when i  click on this image  [image]  if gps is not enabled then i have to show alert box saying gps is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a request and Google added it as a feature (in August 2013 I think). Now you can listen to clicks on the location button like this:

```
final Context context = this;
mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: BUT  AFTER turn on location in location Settings .... still that button is not bringing current location .... so how can i  show  user an alert that "gps IS SEARCHing your location ? "