# How to get an app startup alert asking the user if they wish to turn on locational services?

Tags: android, location, alert

I'm making an app that uses;

```
 map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
```

This is in the onCreate. However I feel it is not right to have users always have location on. There must be an option to turn it off.

I would like a alert/message box (I'm unaware of the technical name) on the app open asking whether the user wishes to turn the location services on, or keep it off.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

`setMyLocationEnabled` Won't actually enable the user's GPS. The user will have to do that by himself otherwise the location will not function.

Just to show that this is true, here's a some-what opposite question that I answered: [Android google map on click of current location button show alert box if gps not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361482/3249477)

Comment: thank you - you brought my attention to a problem and then solved it !

Comment: @user2974706 if the answer solved your problems, select it as correct :)